# System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null on ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I get an error of `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when I try to retrieve my data from a database. I know that EF has a dbcontext that I can use, but I want to try this approach as my colleagues use this kind. I can get the ConnectionString fine, I see it in my breakpoint, but after that line, I get the error:

> System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null

My code is below:

**appsettings.json**

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-MIHT9TM\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=react_db;User=sa;Password=OtlPHP07"
  }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services
                .AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
                })
                .AddNewtonsoftJson()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.WriteIndented = true;
                });

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        }
```

**DepartmentController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DepartmentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

        public DepartmentController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string query = @"SELECT * FROM dbo.Departments";

            var conString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[conString].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        da.Fill(table);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return Ok(table);
        }
    }
```

I encounter the error on this line: `using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[conString].ConnectionString))`

### Edit

This is the value of the conString

[image]

I even tried this code...

```
var conString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[conString].ToString()))
```

Comment: it should be:

using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))

Comment: The DefaultConnection is in my appsettings.json not in the WebConfig, Sir.

Comment: what is the value of "conString" variable/

Comment: @LaxmiLalMenaria, Please see my edit

Comment: you already have connection string so you can directly use 

using (var con = new SqlConnection(conString))

Comment: @LaxmiLalMenaria, You are absolutely right Sir... Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

On the SqlConnection try using the configuration object that is passed on the constructor instead of a new instance of it. Or even better the conString variable you already have (which does use the configuration instance passed on the constructor)

Comment: I didn't create a new instance, SIr. I just used the "coniguration" that was passed. Anyways, I tried doing what you suggested. I directly used the connection string. like so... `conString2 = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");`

Comment: Yes. Sorry I didn’t made myself clear. I mean, on the SqlConnection just use the conString variable instead of looking it up again.